# A problem of Functions of several variables

Tags: calculus, analysis

$f$ is a mapping from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$ and $f$ is differentiable. For any $\lambda$ in $\mathbb{R}$ and any $x$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $f(\lambda x) = \lambda f(x)$, to prove that $f$ is a linear mapping.

Comment: Nice question..

Comment: Compute the derivative of $f(\lambda x)$ with respect to $\lambda$.

Answer (score 0):

Let us fix a point $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$ and define the function $g \: \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ by $g( \lambda) = f (\lambda x) - \lambda f(x)$. Then, by assumtpion, $g(\lambda) = 0$ for all $\lambda$ and hence $g'(\lambda) = 0$. Now, applying the chain rule we obtain
\begin{equation}
0 = g'(\lambda) = \sum_{k = 1}^{n} \partial_k f(\lambda x) x_k - f(x).
\end{equation}
Note that this identity holds for every $\lambda$; in particular, it holds for $\lambda = 0$. Then 
\begin{equation}
f(x) = \langle \nabla f(0), x \rangle
\end{equation}
which proves that $f$ is linear.